# How to copy values from 2d array to doubly linked list

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list

How can I values from 2d array to doubly linked list? I know how to do it with ArrayList but I have no idea how to implement it with doubly linked lists. How could I copy everything from 2d array to LinkedList? Do I need LinkedList of LinkedLists?

If I have

```
int[][] myArray = {{1,2,3}
                              {4,5,6},
                              {7,8,9}};
```

Then the LinkedList should look like exactly the same, i.e.:

```
[[1,2,3]
 [4,5,6],
 [7,8,9];

public void copyFromArray(int[][] myArray){

}

public class Node<Integer> {

    public Integer data;

    public Node<Integer> prev, next;

    public Node( Integer d, Node<Integer> p, Node<Integer> n ){
         this.data = d;
         this.prev = new Node();
         this.next = new Node();
    }

  }
```

Comment: What exactly the end result should be ? You have 2d array of data to put in a simple list (which is like a 1d) . how the data should be entered ?

Comment: You need to have a linkedList class that has a head and a tail node as well. Then you loop through the outer loop, loop through the inner loop, update the latest node with the prev and next. You need to update the head and tail accordingly as well. 

In any case, it is better to give more detailed information so that anyone could help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you need a LinkedList of LinkedLists:

```
LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>> list = new LinkedList<>();
int[][] myArray = { {1, 2, 3}, {4,5,6},{7,8,9} };
for (int i = 0; myArray.length >= i; i++) {
        LinkedList<Integer> auxList = new LinkedList<>();
          for (int j = 0; myArray[i].length >= j; j++) {
            auxList.add(myArray[i][j]);
        }
        list.add(auxList);            
 }
```